# I can't use annotation to the extending class when PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer was extended

Tags: java, spring

I tried extending PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer with MyClass and inject properties through Autowired annotation for Prop1 and XML-based for Prop2. Prop2 works as expected while Prop1 is null. Is there something wrong with my code below?

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.jchips12.test" />

<bean id="prop1" class="com.jchips12.test.Prop1">
    <property name="name" value="Prop1" />
</bean>

<bean id="myClass" class="com.jchips12.test.MyClass">
    <property name="prop2">
        <bean class="com.jchips12.test.Prop2">
            <property name="name" value="Prop2" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="location" value="classpath:environment.properties" />
</bean>
```

MyClass.java

```
public class MyClass extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer{

    @Autowired
    private Prop1 prop1;
    private Prop2 prop2;

    public void setProp2(Prop2 prop2) {
        this.prop2 = prop2;
    }

    ...

}
```

Prop1 and Prop2

```
public class Prop1 {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

public class Prop2 {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `MyClass` is a [BeanFactoryPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html), it is fully instantiated very early in the bean lifecycle, to be able to act on created bean definitions. The `@Autowired` annotations on the other hand are processed by AutoWiredAnnotationPostProcessor which is a [BeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html).

Now since `MyClass` is fully instantiated much earlier, the `AutowiredAnnotationPostProcessor` cannot act on it and inject in the prop1 dependency and hence the failure. It will better to inject in all properties of a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` through explicit configuration itself.

EDIT:
The [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) for @Autowired has a good explanation also - http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html

Comment: I appreaciate your answer and will read the reference you gave before accepting this as an answer, also you have a typo, its not prop2 that is failing, its prop1.